# userbased content from session php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm looking to setup a group field for my custom user script. How can I go about only showing certain content to certain groups

**Example:**

```
admin (all content)
moderator (extended content)
user (user content)
guest (general overview)
```

4 group id's 0 - 4

```
4 banned
3 admin
2 moderator
1 user
0 guest
```

Example of the PHP in use

```
      // Keep reminding the user this account is not active, until they activate
     if($row['group_id'] == 4) { //display all
          echo
          '<div class="info">
          This account is at risk of being banned Please obey the site rules.
          </div>';
      } else {
          exit();
      }
```

Example of the PHP MySQL session

```
/* Displays user information and some useful messages */
session_start();

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
  header("location: http://localhost/login-system/error.php");    
}
else {
    // Makes it easier to read
    $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $active = $_SESSION['active'];
    $group_id = $_SESSION['group_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this example:

Lets say in this is a blog.

```
<?php
// 0 = Banned
// 1 = User
// 2 = Admin
if($_SESSION['group_id'] == 0) {
?>
<h1>You Are Banned</h1>
<?php
} elseif($_SESSION['group_id'] == 1) {
?>
<p>Welcome to my blog.</p>
<?php
} elseif($_SESSION['group_id'] == 2) {
?>
<p>Welcome to my blog.</p><button>Delete Post</button>
<?php
}
```

Or you can do this by a second method:

```
<p id="1">Welcome To My Blog!</p><button id="2">Delete Content</button>
<h1 id="3">You are banned from this website!</h1>
<?php
if($_SESSION['group_id'] == 0) {
echo '<style>
#2 {
display:none;
}
#3 {
display:none;
}
</style>';
} elseif ($_SESSION['group_id'] == 1) {
echo '<style>
#1 {
display:none;
}
#3 {
display:none;</style>';
} elseif ($_SESSION['group_id'] == 2) {
echo '<style>
#1 {
display:none;
}';
}
```

**Hope this helps!**